# Difference between mirror reflected light rays and rays of a screen

Tags: optics, visible-light, reflection

What is the difference between the light rays reflected from a mirror and rays directly emitted from a screen if the screen shows the same image as the mirror would.

Comment: The only difference I think would be due to the fact that a mirror produces a phase shift of $\pi$ after reflection.Other than that,all other "geometrical" aspects should be identical.

Comment: Also the the screen is the source of the light(fluorescent materials in it) while in the case of mirror it's not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Distance to the image is the big difference.

The reflected image in a plane mirror is composed of rays that appear to come from a point *behind* the mirror (by the same distance that the image that is being reflected is in front of the mirror: $d_0 = d_i$). For non-plane mirrors you'll have to work a little harder, but locally spherical bits can be treated with the usual
$$ \frac{1}{f} = \frac{1}{d_i} + \frac{1}{d_o} \,.$$

The light rays emanating from a screen come from the surface of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

A mirror is a surface that produces specular reflection of incident rays. A screen (assuming it's an electronic screen of some kind, not a viewing screen; not that there's much difference) acts as a source of diffuse rays.

For one thing, as dmckee pointed out, the image formed by the mirror will not usually appear to be located at the surface of the mirror. Some mirrors will have the image appear to be located behind the mirror and some can focus the light so that the image appears in from of the mirror. Nevertheless, in all cases, the light rays will not originate from the mirror.

A screen, on the other hand, acts as the source. Light rays originate from the screen and the image (ignoring overlapping imaging techniques) appears to be located at the surface of the screen.

The other difference comes from the type of rays that each surface throws off. With a mirror, you have specular reflection, which means the angle of the reflected ray equals the angle of the incident ray. This means the reflected image is only perfectly visible from precisely one angular orientation. A screen, on the other hand, produces diffuse rays (whether they originate at the screen or are diffusely reflected), which means they spread out in all directions. This also means that you can orient yourself in any reasonable position and see the same image (that's why the eyes of a painting always seem to follow you).

What else can this all mean? The light rays from a screen will not be collimated (parallel). No matter how visually similar an image is, a screen will not produce an image with collimated rays. If you were to shine a laser off a mirror and into your eyes (pro tip: Don't try this at home, kids. Go to a friend's house!) it would be damaging. If you shone that same laser into a camera and displayed it on your screen, it's not damaging at all and the same rays are no longer collimated. Same with a regular viewing screen; the rays won't be collimated if you shine the laser at a white surface and observe the diffuse reflection (Actual safety tip: Do not observe the diffuse reflection of a Class 4 laser without appropriate eye protection. Don't know what a Class 4 laser is? Then you don't have one to worry about). The images will look basically identical, but the rays from a screen originate at the screen and spread out diffusely; whereas the rays from a mirror do not originate at the mirror and are reflected specularly.

Answer (score -1):

A mirror is an object which has reflections occurring on its surface but a screen is the place where there are images forming.